# How to convert long speech to text. Google asyncronous speech recognition in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

Does anyone know how to convert long speech in wav or MP3 format to text, by using Google speech to text asyncronous API ? I am using the code below but I always get an error finding upload_blob() function.

Thanks in advance.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import io
import os
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
import wave
from google.cloud import storage

filepath = "/home/marte/Documentos/Python_Scripts/Law/" 
output_filepath = "/home/marte/Documentos/Python_Scripts/Law/" 
bucketname = "callsaudiofiles" 
def frame_rate_channel(audio_file_name):
    with wave.open(audio_file_name, "rb") as wave_file:
        frame_rate = wave_file.getframerate()
        channels = wave_file.getnchannels()
        return frame_rate,channels
def google_transcribe(audio_file_name):
    file_name = filepath + audio_file_name 
    frame_rate, channels = frame_rate_channel(audio_file_name)
    bucket_name = bucketname
    source_file_name = filepath + audio_file_name
    destination_blob_name = audio_file_name
    upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name)
    gcs_uri = 'gs://' + bucketname + '/' + audio_file_name
    transcript = ''
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=frame_rate,
    language_code='es-CO')
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
    response = operation.result(timeout=10000)
    for result in response.results:
        transcript += result.alternatives[0].transcript
    delete_blob(bucket_name, destination_blob_name)
    return transcript
def write_transcripts(transcript_filename,transcript):
    f= open(output_filepath + transcript_filename,"w+")
    f.write(transcript)
    f.close()
sentencia = google_transcribe("onu-santos.wav")
write_transcripts("onu-santos.txt",sentencia)
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you be more specific?

Comment: NameError: name 'upload_blob' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to solve the problem by setting a new "segment" in my Google Cloud Storage account and setting the credentials as a local variable by:

```
 export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/home/marte/Documentos/Python_Scripts/Speech/sequoia-31501208ed06.json'
```

This link was useful: 
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started